# RSpec and Capybara matchers failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

Been scratching my head for a few hours on this one, and finally need to give up and ask. At least I've learned a bit more about RSpec and Capybara in the meantime, but apparently not enough.

```
subject { page }

describe "Help page" do
  before { visit help_path }
  it { should have_valid_header_and_title('Help', 'Help') }
end
```

Fails with

```
expected #<Capybara::Session> to have valid header and title "Help" and "Help" ./spec/features/static_pages_spec.rb:18:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
-e:1:in `load'
-e:1:in `<main>'
```

I have a matcher for have_valid_header_and_title:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :have_valid_header_and_title do |heading, page_title|
  match do |page|
    if (heading) then
      expect(page.body).to have_selector('h1', text: heading)
    end
    expect(page.body).to have_selector('title', text: full_title(page_title))
  end
end
```

And a helper function for full_title:

```
def full_title(page_title)
  base_title = "Homewatch"
  if page_title.empty?
    base_title
  else
    "#{base_title} | #{page_title}"
  end
end
```

Finally, this is what page.body consists of (using a print inserted to debug):

```
"<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head>\n  <title>Homewatch | Help</title>...
```

Debugging, I see that full_title is returning "Homewatch | Help" which should match on the title element, and there is an h1 element with "Help" in it. So it should pass!

I've tried page.should and page.body.should instead of expect(page.body).to, I've tried has_selector? which just gives an undefined name error, and various other things.

Using rails 3.2.18, rspec-rails 3.1.0, capybara 2.4.4, and capybara-webkit 1.3.1

I'm beginning to suspect a version incompatibility somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. It is a result of this [logged issue](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/844).

The problem is that the title element will not be found by some web drivers (it is considered invisible). This was fixed in Capybara by adding a visible: switch to have_selector and has_selector. I changed my matcher to this:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :have_valid_header_and_title do |heading, page_title|
  match do |page|
    if (heading) then
      expect(page.body).to have_selector('h1', text: heading)
    end
    Capybara.string(page.body).has_selector?('title', text: full_title(page_title), visible: false)
  end
end
```